# When accessing the parent's function in the iframe, it says that 'arrow function' is not a function

Tags: javascript

I tested calling parent's function in iframe. Normal function could be called through parent. But when I use the arrow function I get an "is not a function" error. What is the difference between calling common function and arrow function within iframe? Here is the code I used for testing.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <iframe></iframe>

        <script>
            function a() {
                console.log("a");
            }
            const b = () => {
                console.log("b");
            };
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            let ascript =
                "<scr" + 'ipt type="text/javascript">parent.a();</scr' + "ipt>";
            $("iframe").contents().find("body").append(ascript);
            let bscript =
                "<scr" + 'ipt type="text/javascript">parent.b();</scr' + "ipt>";
            $("iframe").contents().find("body").append(bscript);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with arrow functions. Declaring a variable with `let` or `const` doesn't add it to the `window` object.

Comment: You would have the same problem if you did `const b = function() { console.log("b"); }`

Comment: Change `const` to `var` and it will work.